# Why are Roger and Anita absent in "102 Dalmatians"?

Tags: plot-explanation, 102-dalmatians

In *102 Dalmatians*, Roger (Jeff Daniels) and Anita (Joely Richardson) who starred in the original *101 Dalmatians* are not seen or mentioned.

Why?

Also, how was Dipstick adopted?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: **We don't know**. Never addressed in film or outside the film.

There is a trope for such elements of story called [What Happened to the Mouse?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatHappenedToTheMouse) and even TVTropes mention the same in [films link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/OneHundredAndTwoDalmatians)

> **What Happened to the Mouse?:** The movie makes no mention of Roger or Anita, Pongo or Perdita, or Dipstick's siblings.